# android studio не видит часть классов SDK

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

Доброго времени суток.

При просмотре исходного кода android sdk часть классов sdk подчеркивается красным. Раньше при попытке просмотреть исходники какого-нибудь класса из sdk, все что я мог увидеть - это сигнатура класса и сигнатуры методов, а внутри методов такая строка:

```
throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
```

android studio предлагала мне скачать исходники,что я и сделал. И вот теперь просматривая исходники вижу такое:

[image: Context.java].

Часть классов недоступна. Собранное приложение вылетает на эмуляторе.

Содержимое build.gradle(Project: Maze):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belon
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Содержимое build.gradle(Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bakuard.maze"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
       "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
 }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
    core:3.0.1'
}
```

Пожалуйста, скажите как это исправить.

Comment: скажите, а какая связь между исходниками android, возможностью их просмотра и вылетанием вашего приложения? Если вы пытаетесь внести какие то изменения в классы API и надеетесь, что это будет работать, то сразу оставьте такие попытки - билд собственной сборки андроид занятие сложное, нудное, продолжительное по времени и предполагает квалификацию в этом вопросе выше среднего.

Comment: Нет, я не пытаюсь внести изменения в API. Я полагал, что часть sdk у меня отсутствует либо studio по какой-то причине её не видит. "скажите, а какая связь между исходниками android, возможностью их просмотра и вылетанием вашего приложения?" - я просто описал полседовательность событий после которых у меня случилась эта проблема. Я не уверен что межу ними существует прямая связь, но другого предположения сделать не смог.

Comment: приложите лучше стектрейс ошибки из logcat при падении вашего приложения.